# Localization of TOTP MFA controls

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I've implemented TOTP based MFA as described in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-control-time-based-one-time-password) and samples (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/totp).

Now I would like to translate texts displayed during MFA enrollment and verification. However, I couldn't find anything in documentation regarding `StringId`s which can be overridden using B2C localization mechanism.

There is a similar question on GitHub - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/378, without response since 10 days.

I would like to translate following screens:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate the screens as shown above, you can do the following:

1. In your `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`, under the node `ContentDefinitions`, add the following

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.totp">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.9</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

2. In your `TrustFrameworkLocalization.xml` `ContentDefinitions` node add

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.totp">
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.selfasserted.totp.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="af" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.selfasserted.totp.af" />
          <!-- Add more languages here -->
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
</ContentDefinition>
```

3. Finally, also in the localization xml, you can add the following translations (Change the `.af` to your language preference of course)

```xml
<!-- Edit profile page English-->
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.totp.en">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="DisplayName">You can download the Microsoft Authenticator app or use any other authenticator app of your choice.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="title_text">Scan the QR code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="info_msg">Using your app scan this QR code and click "Continue"</LocalizedString>          
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="link_text">Can&#39;t scan? Try this</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="otpCode" StringId="UserHelpText">Enter the 6-digit verification code generated by the the Authenticator app in the box.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="otpCode" StringId="DisplayName">Enter your code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="QrCodeVerifyInstruction" StringId="DisplayName">Enter the verification code from your authenticator app​.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="QrCodeScanInstruction" StringId="DisplayName">Once you've downloaded the Authenticator app, you can use any of the methods below to continue with enrollment.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorAppIconControl" StringId="title_text">Download the Microsoft Authenticator using the download links for iOS and Android or use any other authenticator app of your choice.</LocalizedString>          
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="title_text">Enter the account details manually</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="account_name">Account Name:</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="display_prefix">Secret</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="collapse_text">Still having trouble?</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Continue</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_cancel">Cancel</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.totp.af">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="DisplayName">Jy kan die Microsoft Authenticator-toepassing aflaai of enige ander Authenticator-toepassing van jou keuse gebruik.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="title_text">Skandeer die QR-kode</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="link_text">Kan jy nie skandeer nie? Probeer hierdie</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="info_msg">Deur jou toepassing te gebruik, skandeer hierdie QR-kode en klik "Gaan voort"</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="otpCode" StringId="UserHelpText">Voer die 6-syfer-verifikasiekode in wat deur die die Authenticator-toepassing gegenereer is in die blokkie.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="otpCode" StringId="DisplayName">Sleutel in jou kode</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="QrCodeVerifyInstruction" StringId="DisplayName">Voer die verifikasiekode vanaf jou verifikasie-toepassing in.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="QrCodeScanInstruction" StringId="DisplayName">Sodra jy die Authenticator-toepassing afgelaai het, kan jy enige van die metodes hieronder gebruik om voort te gaan met inskrywing.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorAppIconControl" StringId="title_text">Laai die Microsoft Authenticator af deur die aflaaiskakels vir iOS en Android te gebruik of gebruik enige ander Authenticator-toepassing van jou keuse.</LocalizedString>          
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="title_text">Voer die rekeningbesonderhede handmatig in</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="account_name">Rekeningnaam:</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="display_prefix">Geheim</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="collapse_text">Het u steeds probleme?</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Gaan voort</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_cancel">Kanselleer</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

This should give you the following output then

[image]

[image]

**NOTE** Some of the error message you will have to test and also figure out how to translate, the codes for these can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids), but I did find one or 2 that does not work as I expect, and still trying to get it all to translate proper. Wish there was better documentation on this